# how to show possible matching suggestions for text being typed in an edittext?

Tags: android, android-edittext, autosuggest

i'm creating an `Application` where there is a part where user needs to enter the `state`,`city` and `district` in an `Edittext`.

while entering the `state` I need to show some possibly matching suggestions with the letters that are typed in the `edittext`. 
I have searched a lot and couldnt find anything useful as per my requirements..

So how do i go about this?? the suggestions of  can come from a sqlite database table... if anybody knows any good example or can guide me through the coding please help...
i have no idea how to do it...

Comment: have you try autocompliter ?

Comment: @AnkitMakwana no i have'nt tried that...what exactly does that do??

Comment: http://www.javatpoint.com/src/android-autocompletetextview-example see

Comment: @AnkitMakwana how do i read that autocompletetextview value into a string in the same activity without a button click event???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AutoCompleteTextView might help you
try it out [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html)

Comment: how do i read that autocompletetextview value into a string in the same activity without a button  click event???

Comment: look for the public methods in the link I posted. there might be several ways as it's not always one String :)

Answer (score 2):

use autocomplete textview and then get your country/state list and set in adapter.

```
public class CountriesActivity extends Activity {
     protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
         super.onCreate(icicle);
         setContentView(R.layout.countries);

         ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                 android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, COUNTRIES);
         AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView)
                 findViewById(R.id.countries_list);
         textView.setAdapter(adapter);
     }

     private static final String[] COUNTRIES = new String[] {
         "Belgium", "France", "Italy", "Germany", "Spain"
     };
 }
```

**setThreshold(int threshold)**

Specifies the minimum number of characters the user has to type in the edit box before the drop down list is shown.

Comment: Is it possible to use a ArrayList for holding countries instead of a string array??

Comment: @KJEjava48 Yes its possible, You can use BaseAdapter class. Ie.CommonAutoCompleteAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable